# Error using another classes method

Tags: java

I made a simple JFrame in my Main class and in my class Move I extended JPanel and put the PaintComponent method. I implemented the KeyListener to control a rectangle I drew on the screen. In my last class, Collision I made a method that returns a boolean but when I try t use that value it get loads of errors.

error in console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.awt.Component.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setBackground(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColors(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Move.<init>(Move.java:15)
    at Collision.<init>(Collision.java:4)
    at Move.<init>(Move.java:11)
    at Collision.<init>(Collision.java:4)
```

and the "at Move.(Move.java:11)" repeats like a 1000 times.

code:

setting up JFrame and gameloop

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Move m = new Move();
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setSize(300,200);
        jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jf.add(m);
        jf.requestFocusInWindow();

        Thread t = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    m.repaint();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

}
```

The Move class using paint component and keylistener. I think it has something to do with c.Left() == true

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Move extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Collision c = new Collision();

    BufferedImage box;

    public Move() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);

    }

    int x = 100, y = 100;
    Boolean goLeft = false;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        if (goLeft == true && c.Left() == true) {
            x--;
        }

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(16, 16, x, y);

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            goLeft = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            goLeft = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

And the Collision class

```
public class Collision{

    Move m = new Move();

    Boolean left;

    public Boolean Left(){
        if(m.x>0){
            left=false;
        }
        return left;
    }

}
```

I hope I said everything clear, thank you.

Comment: What are the "loads of errors"? Provide some of them here.

Comment: You can't have `Move` create a `Collision` and `Collision` create a `Move`. You will get a loop ending in out of memory.

Comment: Collision doesn't even have a constructor..

Comment: +1 to Keppil - you're getting StackOverflowError!

Comment: @Feek: No, so it gets one without arguments automatically.

Comment: @Keppil Your first comment should be made an answer.

Comment: @Keppil Is there any work arounds? Anyway thanks for clarifying what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a `StackOverflowError` since you have a circular dependency. Every `Move` creates a new `Collision`, and every `Collision` creates a new `Move`.

You will have to rethink your design and create at least one of them somewhere else.